# Using AspectJ annotations in maven project: weaving is not working

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin, compile-time-weaving

I am trying to use AspectJ in a simple project without using Spring, and while I have seen similar questions and my code seems to be correct, I don't understand why it's not working. I'm using Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.3 (not using AJDT tools), JDK 7, maven 3.5.2, and my code is as follows:

**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspect-tutorial</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


<properties>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**MainApp.java**

```
package com.pkg;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HelloWorld a = new HelloWorld();
        a.printHello();
    }
}
```

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package com.pkg;

public class HelloWorld {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Print Hello...");
   }

}
```

**TestAspect.java**

```
package com.pkg;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;


@Aspect
public class TestAspect {       

    @Before("execution(* com.pkg.HelloWorld.printHello(..))")
    public void testBefore2(){
        System.out.println("Yeeha");
    }


}
```

Running mvn clean install is successful, but the output only prints the "Print Hello..." part. Should I use a different approach? (Maybe use a .aj file instead, or try load-time-weaving) Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the configuration of both AspectJ Maven and Maven Compiler. My POMs for AspectJ usually look a bit different than yours (a few more settings), but here is yours with minimal changes in order to make it work:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspect-tutorial</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.13</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.11</version>
        <configuration>
          <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- IMPORTANT -->
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
          <!-- IMPORTANT -->
          <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.pkg.MainApp</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

See how I set incremental compilation to `false` for Maven compiler? This is due to an old bug (still unfixed) which actually inverts the switch, so in order to make incremental compilation work you have to "deactivate" it. Very weird.

You also need to define executions for the `process-sources` phase for AspectJ Maven.

Besides, I upgraded to AspectJ Maven 1.11 and thus also to AspectJ runtime 1.8.13.

I also added Maven Exec plugin in order to easily prove that it is working now. Just call `mvn clean compile exec:java` and check the output:

```
(...)
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.11:compile (default) @ aspect-tutorial ---
[INFO] Showing AJC message detail for messages of types: [error, warning, fail]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ aspect-tutorial ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
(...)
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ aspect-tutorial ---
Yeeha
Print Hello...
(...)
```

Otherwise I support what Nándor said: Make sure you use AspectJ plugins for Eclipse or IDEA if you also want to run your aspect-enhanced Java code from an IDE.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to run it, indeed now it works as you said. I have one more question though, how would it be possible to build a jar out of this app and use it as a dependency in another project (say a web service) with working weaving? I tried an mvn install and run the produced jar but I got a "NoAspectBoundException" exception. This  may need a different question but I'd be glad if you could point me to the right direction.

Comment: Yes, a new question would be better. But I am sure I have answered it here before, so you could search first. If you do ask, then please explain better what you mean by "working weaving". Are you talking about load-time weaving, using this artifact as an aspect library for other code? Or is is just about making sure the compile-time woven code finds its AspectJ runtime classes?

Answer (score 2):

How you you run your app? Purely from maven or from within Eclipse? Do you have Eclipse to automatically build your projects? If yes, you probably won't have too much success with compile time weaving, because Eclipse will overwrite your Maven built classes with Eclipse built classes. Without the AJDT feature installed, and properly set up workspace project with AspectJ nature, the resulting compiled code won't be "enhanced" by the AspectJ weaver.

Comment: I was trying to run it both from maven and Eclipse, to figure out how it works. Thanks for the input, I have a better understanding on it now.